# Passing value from parent to child lwc showing undefined

Tags: lightning-web-components

My parent JS code is:

```
    @api recordId;

        getMapData(){
                fetchdata()
                    .then(result => {
                        this.data = result;
                        this.error = null;
                        console.log('Data Connected callback' + JSON.stringify(this.data));
                        this.recordId = this.data[0].Id;
                    })
                    .catch(error =>{
                        this.error = error;
                        this.errorMsg = error;
                        this.isEmpty = true;
                    });  
            }
connectedCallback(){
        this.getMapData();
    }
```

Parent HTML :

```
<template>
   <c-map-field-table get-id-from-parent={recordId} ></c-map-field-table>
</template>
```

Child JS :

```
@api getIdFromParent;
```

getIdFromParent value is 'undefined'

Comment: What is the context of how recordId is populated on the parent? Is it on a record detail page?

Comment: No @stackasaur, as you can see above the recordId is getting populated from the data returned from Apex method call.

Comment: @stackasaur I forgot to check the recordId before sending it to the child component. Now its working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check if recordId is defined before leaving parent component?

```
<template if:true={recordId}>
    <c-map-field-table get-id-from-parent={recordId} ></c-map-field-table>
</template>
```

Comment: Yes it worked. @Klecool

Comment: I added a check to show the child component only when its parameters are filled. Thanks a bunch